# Binary of charcodes to legible string?

Tags: elixir

I'm confused about binaries and strings in Elixir. I have a function. That returns a binary of character codes that represents a string, but I can't figure out how to print that string in a legible way. I was thinking of converting the binary to a character list then enumerating the character list and converting each char to a string, but that seems like a lot of work. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please paste the code in question.

Comment: In addition to answer by @Brandon, please see my answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094791/shell-represents-binary/36099186#36099186 At the end I mention `IO.inspect binary, [{:binaries, :as_strings}]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`String.chunk/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#chunk/2)

```sh
iex(1)> a = "Hello " <> <<0>> <> "World"
<<72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 0, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100>>
iex(2)> String.chunk(a, :printable)     
["Hello ", <<0>>, "World"]
```

Comment: There is also: `IO.inspect a, [{:binaries, :as_strings}]`, which escapes non printable characters.

Comment: Hey @tkowal, would it be ok to ask how this works? I'm new to Elixir. Is the list an argument to "inspect"?

Comment: @KingDan Yes, the second optional argument to `inspect` is list of options: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html